# Do acyl halides react similarly to alkyl halides with nitriles with TBAB/NaOH?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am referencing page pg. 665 in Clayden where it is shown that a nitrile can be alkylated using an alkyl halide with tetraalkylammonium chloride and NaOH. Would acyl halides behave similarly resulting in substitution at the carbon adjacent to the nitrile group?

Comment: You mean on alpha carbon? No, you'd think so?

Comment: Think they would hydrolyse with the tetraalkylammonium hydroxide as they are way more sensitive to hydrolysis than nitriles. Plus if they do deprotonate the halide can leave to give you the ketene.

Comment: I would be more worried about the alkyl halide hydrolyzing than the nitrile, but according to the text the alkylation still occurs. The procedures for hydrolyzing nitriles that I have read involve acidic conditions at reflux.